# Get wrong POST data request, Node JS express

Tags: node.js, express

I try to parse POST request from other server and for some reason I get it as JSON key.

Here is snippets of code:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 ...   

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.post('/sync/:method', onPostRequest);

 var onPostRequest = function(req,res){

   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.params);
}
```

Server sends me JSON data:

```
{
  "sync": [
    {
      "provider_email": "myemail@gmail.com",
      "provider_name": "google",
      "provider_hostname": "none"
    }
  ]
}
```

but Node JS get it as:

```
{
'{"sync":[{"provider_email":"myemail@gmail.com","provider_name":"google","provider_hostname":"none"}]}':
 '' }
```

As you see its `{key: value}` object where `value` = `''` and `key` is:
'[{"provider_email":"myemail@gmail.com","provider_name":"google","provider_hostname":"none"}]}'

What Im doing wrong?

I tried to set `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` and got:

```
{ '{"sync":': { '{"provider_email":"myemail@gmail.com","provider_name":"google","provider_hostname":"none"}': '' } }
```

Maybe  nodejs does “json_encode” on my string, which is already json encoded

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the server is sending a JSON string, but it's using the wrong `Content-Type` header (making Express think that the data is actually url-encoded).